# PowerShell Command to get DotNet4Update3

Tags: powershell

Wanted to know whether DotNet4full version and used below command and got the desired result.

Script:

```
(Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse |
    Get-ItemProperty -Name Version, Release -EA 0 | 
    Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(Full)'} | 
    Select PSChildName, Version, Release ).Version
```

However I am confused how to know the version of **DotNet4Update3** using PowerShell script?

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked some questions having some valid answers but you've not marked any post as answer. It seems you need to take a [Tour].

Comment: You also have the permission to upvote answers. When you accept an answer it's a [good idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) to upvote it. You can accept just one answer, but if you found some other answers useful as well, you can upvote them also. Accepting and upvoting are not compulsory at all, but it's a way to mark worked solutions and useful answers to help future readers to find solutions more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Minimum value of the release DWORD` is mentioned alongside the `version` of .NET Framework installed in your machine, at [msdn documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#ps_a).

For example, if you want to check whether .NET Framework 4.6.2 or higher is installed, regardless of Windows OS version, you can use the query

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemProperty -Name Release | ForEach-Object { $_.Release -ge 394802 }
```

You can replace `394802` in the above example with another value from the table you can find at the website mentioned above, to check for a different minimum-required .NET Framework version. If you have the `Release DWORD` of `update3`, you can refer to the table and replace the value in the above command accordingly.

Comment: I used below
C:\Users\PShanbh1>powershell "Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framewo
rk Setup\NDP\' "


Name                           Property
----                           --------

v3.0                           Version   : 3.0.30729.5420
                               CBS       : 1
                               Increment : 5420
                               Install   : 1
                               SP        : 2
Does it means Update 3 is there ?